# Why can't I pass a 2D array as a pointer to pointer but can pass a 1D array as a pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

Apperantly this code works

```
void printD(int * ar,int r)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < r; i++)
            cout<<ar[i]<<endl;
    }
int main()
{
    int ar[3] = {1,2,3};
    printD(ar,3);
    return 0;
}
```

But this code does not work

```
void print2D(int ** ar,int r,int c)
    {
        for( int i = 0; i< r;i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < c;j++)
            cout<<ar[i][j]<<endl;
    }
int main()
{

   int ar2[1][2] = {{3,1}};
   print2D(ar2,1,2);
    return 0;
}
```

I do not understand why this does not work?

Comment: A 2D array is not a pointer to pointer.  It's a pointer to a 2D array.

Comment: This is more C code than C++ (except for `cout`). If you **really** want to go with C++, you should consider using standard containers (`std::vector`). And pass references.

Comment: In the old good time of KR C language, we were often using such terrible things as int ar2[2][2] = {{3,1},{2, 4}}; print1D((int *) ar2, 4); Not to show to children, but it was working ... Better define your own matrix type, or use a library

Comment: The former terrible example helps understanding why `ar[2][2]` is _not_ an `int **`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem lies within how the memory addresses are calculated. `a[0]` is the first element, and `a[1]` is the second element, so the address of `a[1]` is the position of `a[0]` plus the size of the element. No problem here, the address of any element can be calculated with the position of the first element multiplied with the offset times the element size.

How does this work with multi-dimensional arrays? What's the distance between `a[0][5]` and `a[1][5]`? Well, that depends on the row size (I'm using this terminology for the sake of this example, in reality, there aren't any "rows"), since in the end it's just one block of memory. If a row has 10 elements, then the distance is 10 times the size of an element. So this row size is important, the exact location of the elements in the array can't be calculated without it. Now with this here:

```
void print2D(int ** ar,int r,int c)
```

How could it know that row size? `ar[1][0]` is the first element of the second row, so if a row had size 10, then that would be the 10th element in the memory block. However, if the row size is 20, then it would be the 20th element, and that would be a different address. So how would it know?

The code doesn't work because it would require information to calculate the addresses, but it doesn't have that information.

Answer (score 3):

This array `int ar2[1][2]` actually decays to `int(*)[2]`.

There is no intermediate pointer to pointer that gets allocated, there is a contiguous 1D array that has can be accessed in 2D, hence the remaining [2] that gives the stride to go from one row to another.

Answer (score 3):

A 2-dimensional array is implicitly converted to a pointer to a 1D array, not to a pointer to a pointer.

```
void print2D(int (*ar)[2],int r,int c)
{
     //  definition omitted for brevity
}
int main()
{

   int ar2[1][2] = {{3,1}};
   print2D(ar2,1,2);
   return 0;
}
```

There is also no conversion from a pointer to an array (as in the above sample) into a pointer to pointer.

For more dimensions, this also works - except that all dimensions other than the first must be known at compile time.